# How to move from an in-memory DB to a persistant one in spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Java Spring Boot and I've been working on a Library app with PostgreSQL as the DB. In my implementation, I'd like to create a table as soon as the application starts. However, when the program is closed the table disappears.

This is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/library
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

server.error.include-message=always
```

I have tried using all the options under hibernate.ddl-auto, but nothing seems to create one.

This is my config file to insert some initial data into the table.

```
@Configuration
public class BookConfig {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(BookRepository repository){
        return args -> {
            Book mockingbird = new Book(
                    "mockingbird",
                    1,
                    "in-stock",
                    0
                    );

            Book artOfDeception = new Book(
                    "art-of-deception",
                    1,
                    "in-stock",
                    0
            );

            Book blackHatPython= new Book(
                    "black-hat-python",
                    2,
                    "in-stock",
                    0
            );

            repository.saveAll(
                    List.of(mockingbird, artOfDeception, blackHatPython)
            );

        };
    }
}
```

Do I have to feed in an SQL schema? I came across JPA EntityManager which I thought would help, but I am not able to understand how to use it.

TL;DR: my goal is to make the app create a table and have that table still existing even after closing the application.

Comment: @tbjorch no when i run the application, it creates the table successfully. i can do the CRUD operations i have set up on it too. when i close the application or restart it, everything on the table resets. i want the table to stay with the same data even after restart.

Comment: That's what the create-drop does.

if you use `update`
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
It should not drop tables even after app is stopped

Comment: @ArfatBinkileb i did try that, it doesnt drop it but it is appending the initial columns on the existing table on start up.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. If you want to drop only data on each startup and not the whole table then add this line to your runner:   repository.deleteAll(); before saving new data

Comment: You can use `update` as that will make the table match the entity, but in a very crude way. It is not recommended to have hibernate manage your schema (although you can use it for prototyping). To manage your schema (and maybe initial data) you want to use somthing like Flyway or Liquibase. That way you can optimize your tables with indexes, column positions etc. etc.